# Disabling keyboard navigation in WPF ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox, keyboard

How do I disable keyboard navigation in a WPF ListBox without disabling selection using the mouse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Handle the `PreviewKeyDown` event to and set `e.Handled` to true (you could check and disable only certain keys/modifiers which are provided with the [KeyEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.aspx) passed to the handler):

XAML:

```
<ListBox PreviewKeyDown="listBox_PreviewKeyDown">
  <ListBoxItem Content="asdfasdf" />
  <ListBoxItem Content="asdfasdf" />
  <ListBoxItem Content="asdfasdf" />
</ListBox>
```

Code behind:

```
private void listBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  e.Handled = true;
}
```