# How to prevent keyboard navigation?

Tags: wpf

consider this: i've got a bunch of Buttons inside a StackPanel, how do i disable navigation between those buttons?

KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None" is doing part of the job - it is disabling the navigation with the Tab key, but still i can navigate with the arrows left/right.

how do i disable this at all?

Comment: Why would you want to cripple the usability of your application?

Comment: calm down... it is not just an application, its got a game in it. what i actually need is once the game panel was init and the panel got focus prevent keyboard navigation out of the panel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling keyboard navigation in WPF ListBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639307/disabling-keyboard-navigation-in-wpf-listbox)

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to change `KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation` ?

You can find a post about it here from Min Zhu : [Keyboard Navigation Tips](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/b25bb4b8-93cf-4c56-88d1-0690965d728f)